# How to access a block device in virtual machine in Xen

Tags: configuration, virtual-machine, xen

I need rw access to block device e.g. /dev/mmcblk0 in VM in Xen. Is it possible to passthrough an address range? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "Is it possible to passthrough an address range?" I know how to pass a block device to a guest but I'm unsure what is meant by that additional constraint.

Comment: thanks, i have found solution

Comment: If you want to be helpful to others you could post your solution as an answer & mark it as accepted.

Comment: sorry, i done the job in Dom0, it was the solution

Comment: thank you for reply